# How do I get Python warnings to display during (nose) test execution?

Tags: python, nose

I'm using `nose` as my Python unit test runner. One of my tests confirms that very large input files can be handled without causing a `MemoryError`. The test passes on my machine, but on Travis (CI) the test runs for too long without output so Travis halts the test.

To fix this situation (and provide a better message to the user), I've started using the `warnings` modules to display warnings when large files are read:

```
WARNING: file contains greater than 100000 rows
WARNING: file contains greater than 200000 rows
WARNING: file contains greater than 300000 rows
# etc.
```

These warnings display when using the program normally, but `nose` seems to capture/suppress these warnings.

How do I get warnings to display while tests are running without modifying `nose`'s existing logging capture behavior?

Answer (score 0):

To test warnings, you use the [`catch_warnings`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#testing-warnings) context manager.  So within a test, you can check that a function created a warning.  Actually outputting the warning during testing shouldn't matter.

Within a test:

```
with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
    warnings.simplefilter("always")
    operate_on_25000_row_file()
    assert len(w) == 1
    assert "20000 rows" in str(w[-1].message)
```

You could also try forcing printing, or treat all warnings as exceptions for the test runner to pick up:

```
warnings.simplefilter('always')  # always print
# or
warnings.simplefilter('error')  # raise exceptions
```

Travis CI also [documents](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/#my-builds-are-timing-out) how to deal with build timeouts on their service.